# Error on passing multiple parameters to a Report Viewer

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

I'm trying to learn my way around VS 2013 using VB.net and its Report Viewer. I want to know how to pass a string to a parameter basically. And hopefully move on to other methods/procedures. Anyway I have a problem with this particular code block:

```
With Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport
    .ReportPath = "C:\Users\Kim\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Tests\Tests\Report1.rdlc"
    .DisplayName = "Test Report"
    .DataSources.Clear()
End With
Me.ReportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.Normal)
Dim rpT As New ReportParameter("rpTitle", "Huehuehue")
Dim rpD As New ReportParameter("rpDate", "This day")

Dim HeaderParams As ReportParameter() = {rpT, rpD}
For Each param As ReportParameter In HeaderParams
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(param)
Next
```

If I comment out `Dim rpD As New ReportParameter("rpDate", "This day")` and change this line `Dim HeaderParams As ReportParameter() = {rpT}`, the `rpT` part will show correctly on the report form. The result is relatively the same if I exclude `rpT` instead. If I use both I get a `Some parameters or credentials have not been specified` on my report. I've been hovering around Google for sometime now but nobody else seems to have this kind of problem.

Comment: Apparently this problem is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Apparently you had to declare it as `New ReportParameter()` in the `SetParameters`. I don't know how to use an array there. But then again I'd still need to list all the parameters, so that'd be redundant. If anybody can improve this that would be great.

```
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(New ReportParameter() {rpT, rpD})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I send parameter values:

1) create a generic list of type ReportParameter

2) add your new parameters to the list with a parameter name and value and visibility

3) set the parameters for the LocalReport

```
    Dim paramList As New Generic.List(Of ReportParameter)
    paramList.Add(New ReportParameter("ReportTitle", stgReportTitle, True))
    paramList.Add(New ReportParameter("ReportFooter", stgReportFooter, True))
    Me.vwrReport.LocalReport.SetParameters(paramList)
```

Always works!